# Imagem sobre um texto

Tags: javascript, css

Eu achei um codigo de voce passar o mouse e mostrar um texto, eu gostaria que mostrasse uma foto.

Pode ser feito com css ou javascript mas eu nao sei a parte da foto.
tipo isso

```
<style>
#mostrar{<br />
  display:none;<br />
  }<br />
</style>

<div id="passar_mouse">Passar o mouse</div>
<div id="mostrar">http://tcgbrasil.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/Sem-Título-1-600x600.png</div>
<script>
$('#passar_mouse').mouseover(function(){
  $('#mostrar').css('display', 'block');
});

$('#passar_mouse').mouseout(function(){
  $('#mostrar').css('display', 'none');
});  
    </script>
```

---

Mas gostaria que a imagem aparecer flutuante, vou te mostrar oq eu ja tenho , porem é um plugin no wordpress. [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3):

Acabei de fazer este pequeno código e acho que é isto que falas:

```js
$("#texto").hover(function () {
 $("#image").css('display', 'block');
  $(this).mousemove(function(e){
     $("#image").css({left:e.pageX + 15, top:e.pageY + 15});
  });
}, function () {
   $("#image").css('display', 'none');
});
```

```css
#image{
position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="image" src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/55fc0004e4b069a519961e2d/t/55fc301ae4b01342ae9212a1/1442590746805/" style="display:none;"/>

<div id="texto">
passa aqui o mouse
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado , acho que esse vai me servir.

Comment: O meu nao fica seguindo o mouse.

Comment: tem certeza ? é que aqui funciona tudo

Answer (score 1):

Nao entendi bem o que quer, mas seria isso?

```js
$('.mouse').mouseover(function(){
  $('.mostrar').show()
})

$('.mouse').mouseout(function(){
  $('.mostrar').hide()
})
```

```css
.mostrar{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mouse">Passe o mouse aqui</div>
  <div class="mostrar">
    <img src="http://images.indianexpress.com/2016/10/got-759.jpg">
  </div>
```